# how could I display a border around a picture with a button using VueJS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuejs2

I try to display a border around a picture with a button using VueJS,this border is displayed normally on my button. I understand that but I don't understand how to link the button and the image in order to display the border around the picture.

```
Vue.component('my-button', 'my-img' {
  template: `<button :class="classObj" @click="toggleState()">My Button</button>
  <my-img :src="image1" @click="toggleState()" :class="classObj" >`,

  props: {
    state: {
      type: String
    }
  },

  data () {
    return {
      isActive: false, 
    }
  },

  computed: {
    classObj () {
      return {
        [this.state]: this.isActive
      }
    }
  },

  methods: {
    toggleState () {
      this.isActive = this.isActive ? false : true;
    }
  }
});

const App = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
     image1 :"http://emersontech.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/java.jpg",
  },

});
```

Comment: you've got error in your pen code at the first line.

Comment: you have to create the components separately, like `Vue.component('my-button',template:'<>'` and `Vue.component('my-img',template:'<>'`

Comment: think you I will try

Comment: i understand that you want when you click on the button you will get a border around button and picture in the same time?

Comment: not exactly I want to have the border just around the picture but here I just code around the button because I don't understand how can I add the border with the button around the picture

Comment: ah ok, you want when you click on the button your picture will be bordered?

Comment: yes it is exactly what I want to create with Vuejs

Comment: ok i will do that for you

Comment: think you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed your code to achieve the desired result by emitting an event from the button to parent component in order to change the state, so you don't need to create a component for your image and you could simply use the `<img .../>` tag in the parent template. Also you have to know that the communication between a parent component and child one is guaranteed using `props` and `this.$emit()` function.
[here the working solution](https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/337564/)

Comment: thank you I will check your code in order to understand my errors

Comment: I've never used Vue.js at all but it annoyed me that the picture was moving when the border was applied so I did a fix for that: https://jsfiddle.net/njfife/0zb3xvL4/ my solution kinda disables the whole "active" thing, so you should do it better than I did. However please don't let the image move like that. So annoying =)

Comment: and if we want it for several picture with several button, one button for one picture, how we can do this please? because I try to create a table with your code as a base but I failed. Can you give me some advises please?